# How to change tableVIew height depending on the size of screen in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I am developing iOS App.

I use tableView in a view in Storyboard(Auto layout).
In the storyboard, the height of the tableView is set in 568px.

I would like to change the height depending on the size of screen.

I am writing down the following code, however I can't.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIScreen *sc = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    CGRect rect = sc.applicationFrame;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
 }
```

Could you tell me how to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set following constraints that will help `UITableView` to occupied whole screen.

```
Leading Space = 0 from mainView
Top Space = 0 from mainView
Bottom Space = 0 from mainView 
Trailing Space = 0 from mainView
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

since you are using auto layout, you can give the tableview constraints, top and bottom = 0 so that its height will always be equal to the height of its container